# Failed to load font in SFML

Tags: c++, xcode, fonts, sfml

```
if (!font.loadFromFile("sansation.ttf"))
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to load font   ";
            return -1;
        }
```

Here is my code when I try to compile I get this error: Failed to load font "sansation.ttf" (failed to create the font face)
Failed to load font   Program ended with exit code: 255

Can anyone help me I have tried ./sansation.ttf I have tried the full directory and yet still no results I am using XCode.

Any help will be appreciated thanks,
Rhys

Comment: Somebody described similar issue here: https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=15406.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I had to
Select "Edit Scheme…" in the "Product" menu;

- Check the box "use custom working directory";
- Fill the text field with the folder path containing your resources;